# How to make SSL reads block?

Tags: sockets, ssl, openssl, blocking

I am trying to make SSL_read() *block* until data is received from the server. I tried setting the socket to blocking in my "connect" code like so

```
  {
    u_long iMode = 1;
    i = ioctlsocket(sock, FIONBIO, &iMode);
  }
```

but strangely I get a stack overflow exception every time.
**Is there another more correct way to do this?**
(Note: the app works just fine if I omit this code).
I've searched SO on this issue but everywhere people seem to have just the opposite problem, namely blocking when they want non-blocking.

**Code Synopsis:**

```
Get method: TLS_client_method()
Get CTX: SSL_CTX_new(method)
Create socket 'sock'
set socket to blocking (code above)
Connect sock to host on port 443
Create SSL*: ssl=SSL_new(ctx)
SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock)  
Do SSL_reads and writes
```

Comment: It blocks by default. You have set it to *non*-blocking mode. Read the documentation. Or note the flag: NBIO: Non-Blocking I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved what I wanted by switching from SSL_* calls to BIO_* calls for connect, read, write, etc..

The BIO family includes function 'BIO_set_nbio()' which sets blocking/nonblocking mode. Worked great.

**Sample Code Synopsis (e.g., for google.com):**

```
Get method: method = TLS_client_method()
Get CTX: ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method)
Create BIO object: bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect( ctx )
Create socket 'sock'
Connect 'sock' to google.com, port 443
Create SSL*: ssl = SSL_new(ctx)
SSL_set_mode( ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY )
BIO_set_conn_hostname( bio, "google.com:443" )
BIO_do_connect( bio )
BIO_set_nbio( bio, mode ) (with mode=0 for blocking)
Now can do blocking BIO_reads and writes (with BIO_read, BIO_write)
```

Comment: You achieved what you stated you wanted by omitting the code in your question. All you've accomplished here is losing SSL altogether.

Comment: I added the new code to my answer. I don't know what you mean by "losing" SSL.